# Two spinners look different in same activity

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

My application activity Image

[image]

First spinner is using string array resources. and second is from arrayList in XML file

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnExam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/Exams" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnPaper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Code for spinner two

```
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            c.moveToFirst();
            do 
            {
                list.add(c.getString(2));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spnPaper.setAdapter(adapter);
            db.close();
```

Comment: just check my second answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem to set View resource for Second spinner. If you need same spinner as first spinner that you have to change by this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

for your second spinner in your java file..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Difference is the using style. You insert data to your first spinner(spnExam) from a string array which will specify the simple list layout to use when the list of choices appears.

But the second spinner which get data through adapter specify the simple spinner list layout to use when the list of choices appears .

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

I think to if you want to same both of your spinner layout then you have to use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` **instead of**  `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`
before you want to show your list i.e on `setDropDownViewResource` method.

If same problem happens then also change your adapter from:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code for both spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your spinner view so change your code android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item to android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.

eg :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

My first answer describes the differences for your problem.

And these are your solutions:

1st solution:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            ListSpinners.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spnPaper.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2nd Solution As before:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            ListSpinners.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spnPaper.setAdapter(adapter);
```

3rd And Expected Solution:

```
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                ListSpinners.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnPaper.setAdapter(adapter);
```

All are useful for you.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListSpinners.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
```